# Rails rspec how to catch error AASM::InvalidTransition and ActiveModel::ValidationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to test call method where I'm using `rescue` from two errors - `AASM::InvalidTransition` and ActiveModel::ValidationError and send it to rollbar. If status doesn't exist it should show the error of validation.

```
def call
  all_to_expire.each do |offer|
    begin
      offer.expire!(actor: self)
    rescue AASM::InvalidTransition, ActiveModel::ValidationError => e
      Rollbar.error(e)
    end
  end
end
```

Specs:

```
context 'when offer is invalid' do
    before do
      allow(BankOffers::CloseExpired).to receive(:new).and_return(invalid_expire)
      allow(invalid_expire).to receive(:call).and_raise(ActiveModel::ValidationError)
    end

    let(:invalid_expire) { instance_double(BankOffers::CloseExpired, call: nil) }

    it 'catch validation error' do
      expect do
        invalid_expire
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::ValidationError)
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

All specs updated - I think I have to use `instance_double` and rise an error by mock all service but at the end I've got an error:

> ```
>   expected ActiveModel::ValidationError but nothing was raised
> ```

Comment: Are you sure your setup should actually raise the exception you want? Use byebug, stop the execution inside the `call` method right before calling `.expire!` and inspect the objects, maybe you don't have the state you need for the code to raise an exception.

Comment: Ok @arieljuod you are right, I don't have an example which can failed. My question is how to get one which will be passed to call method, with invalid field and rise validation error. And yes, I want this `rescue` for sure

Comment: For what I see I have to use mock (?) to fake the implementation and force an error, but I've no idea how to do so...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mock or stub this object because then you won't be testing anything, you will just test that you set up the right mocks which is useless.

I would do something like:

```
context 'when offer is invalid' do
  it 'catch validation error' do
    # this is the tricky part, you are not showing your model so I don't
    # know what's an invalid AASM transition, but you should set an status
    # that can't be transitioned to "expired" here
    invalid_offer = create(:bank_offer,
      inquiry_process: process_past_date_of_interest,
      status:  <<<something here>>>)

    expect(Rollbar).to receive(:error)
    invalid_offer.call
  end
end
```

You need to create a valid record but with a status that can't be transitioned to `epired`. Then you add the expectation on the Rollbar object and then you call the method that should throw the AASM exception. Make sure your object is valid so you don't have other error hidding the actual error you are testing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I found the different way to have invalid value, so when you pass in advisor from different bank. Something like `create(:bank_offer, etc, etc, bank_advisor: advisor (which is another let with proper value)`. In this way bank advisor is not from the same bank. So now in console I've got error which is: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Bank advisor is not from the same bank` and still nothing, zero green dots. However I think your way of thinking is good.